# How to change Gradle version in Eclipse using Buildship?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, buildship

I am running Eclipse Luna SR2 with Buildship 1.0.1.

The Gradle projects I create using the wizard are building with Gradle 2.5-rc-2, but I would like to use 2.6 which is the latest version.

How can I do it?

Setting the task had no effect:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.6'
}
```

Solution:
For some reason it is only working if I restart Eclipse after setting the version as Makoto suggested.

Comment: I just want to make certain:  you've run the `wrapper` task, right?  Have you executed `./gradlew --version` or the Windows equivalent?

Comment: Yes, wrapper task and no, not using command line I wish to do it from the IDE. But once I restarted Eclipse it worked. Not sure why =O . I will try at my PC at home to see if the same happens so I can report a bug.

Comment: @Makoto Your asnwer is correct, but I had to restart Eclipse for it to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use the wrapper, it's a simple matter of setting the `gradleVersion` property:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.6'
}
```

Comment: if running from the command line you could also do:
gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 2.6

Comment: This doesn't update the `build.gradle` file in my experience.

Comment: it won't update the build.gradle file, but it will update the gradle version in the gradle wrapper. In buildship I had to restart eclipse to get it to work regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `Run Configuration` of type `Gradle Project` running the task `wrapper`. Running this run configuration should update the wrapper version without the need to restart eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with different versions. The solution is to add the following task to your build file, then run gradle wrapper task in the project root folder:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion = '2.6'
}
```

The reason the wrong version of wrapper was used for the build is that there was no wrapper created for the version I wanted to use.